# Not able to run hello world servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am trying out following servlet example in my ubuntu PC:

http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Following is directory structure under Tomcat.

[image: web app tree structure]

Java class:

```
   package com.mkyong;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class ServletDemo1 extends HttpServlet{

        public void doGe(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException{
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
```

web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>com.mkyong.ServletDemo1</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/Demo1</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Tomcat server is started as I am able to see default web page for `http://localhost:8080`

To run servlet, I used the URL `http://localhost:8080/servlet/Demo1`

But getting error as "HTTP Status 404 - /servlet/Demo1".

Tomcat version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)

What could be missing? 
Thanks.

Comment: You did everything as described in his tutorial ? With not a single error ?

Comment: check the `servlet-name` in the `web.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I captured tomcat logs using following command

```
# tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
```

After this I came to know that, web application deployment directory is /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ not /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/.

Moved the directory structure to new location.

As suggested by @silk_route11, there was a mistake in method name doGet().
Didn't made any changes in `<servlet-name>`.

Now, able to see the output on browser.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The method of `HttpServlet` is `doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)` not `doGe()`. That can be a mistake..Check the `servlet-name` and `url-pattern` in the `web.xml`.
I think the `servlet-name` should be `ServletDemo1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look to Tomcat admin page to find out whether the application has started correctly or not.