# Servlet : Not able to run the Hello World Program

Tags: java, servlets

Not duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094009/not-able-to-run-hello-world-servlet)

Here is my code

HelloWorld.java

```
// Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

  private String message;

  public void init() throws ServletException
  {
      // Do required initialization
      message = "Hello World";
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Actual logic goes here.
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
  }

  public void destroy()
  {
      // do nothing.
  }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Servlet</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

there is no compilation error, however facing this issue.

[image]

Please help!!
[image]

I changed url to

```
http://localhost:8080/Servlet/HelloWorld
```

and now facing exception

[image]

Folder Structure

[image]

Comment: `<url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>` Why do you think your servlet has to be at `contextroot/Servlet`?

Comment: Upload the full project

Comment: @Everv0id i run it from eclipse , it gave me that path by default

Comment: What server do you use?

Comment: i edit some part. please check will help you to know the issue

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal, as MChaker said, sometimes it depends on what server you use, so what are you using?

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal Btw, show us also your jsp/html file.

Comment: @Drumnbass no jsp as of now .Directly calling `http://localhost:8080/Servlet/HelloWorld` from browser

Comment: What is the full name of `HelloWorld` class? package_name.class_name. Or you are working on the default package?

Comment: @MChaker using default package

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal Eclicpse Kepler is an IDE, not a server. I presume that you mean GlasFish, don't?

Comment: @Drumnbass ohh sorry. slip from mind. its tomcat

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal Anyway, I've never called a servlet from the browser and I don't know if it is possible. I have always called it from a jsp or html file using the POST or GET methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify if there is another application working on the same port as Apache Tomcat.
2. Try to clean your Apache Tomcat server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the class name with the package name.

However, I would recommend to try using @WebServlet(name = "HelloWorld", urlPatterns = "/helloWorld") above the servlet class.

so if owuld be :

@WebServlet(name = "Welcome", urlPatterns = "/testPage")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

//blah blah
}

Comment: `You should provide the class name with the package name`. ... Already done but not working

Comment: What is the name of the folder where your webapp is deployed?

Comment: added the folder structure

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal and java folder structure?

Comment: right cliick on the servers and make sure the tomcat installation is overriden with your custom tomcat installation,

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to check :
- first that the application is deployed corectly on the server. You should have a .war project that is deployed. You should see a successful deployment on you server  logs
- Build your url. This is composed of server IP, in your case local host, than port 8080 is usually the default, than context root (if not defined than it should be the name of the application) and last the servlet name: http://localhost:8080/appname/helloworld

There is also an possible error on your Web.xml. The servlet class tag you defined your class but has no package. Probably you have the class also in a package. 
package. HelloWorld